# I want to Add a foreignkey for a table using onModelCreating method in asp.net core

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I created two tables named 'patient' and 'Admission'.For do that i created patient model and admission model classes.then i use HospitalDbContext class for creating tables using onModelCreating method. I want to use PatientId as a foreign-key of Admission table.But i can't find a way to add foreign key.Help me to solve this problem

***Patient.cs :***

```
public class Patient
    {
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Nic { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
        public string CurrentState { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

***Admission.cs :***

```
 public class Admission
    {
        public int AdmissionId { get; set; }
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
        public DateTime AdmissionDate { get; set; }
        public string reason { get; set; }
    }
```

***HospitalDbContext.cs :***

```
public class HospitalDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public HospitalDbContext(DbContextOptions<HospitalDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
       
        public DbSet<Admission> Admissions { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.PatientId);
                entity.Property(e => e.FirstName);
                entity.Property(e => e.LastName);
                entity.Property(e => e.Nic);
                entity.Property(e => e.Age);
                entity.Property(e => e.Address);
                entity.Property(e => e.Email);
                entity.Property(e => e.Mobile);
                entity.Property(e => e.RegisterDate);
                entity.Property(e => e.CurrentState);
                entity.Property(e => e.Password);
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<Admission>(entity=> 
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.AdmissionId);
                entity.Property(e => e.PatientId);
                entity.Property(e => e.AdmissionDate);
                entity.Property(e => e.reason);
            
            });
        }

        public DbSet<patient_information_system_api.Models.Admission> Admission { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, we couldn't directly create the relationship without modifying the your Patient and Admission class.

If you want to achieve one to one relationship between the `Admission` and `Patient`, you should add Admission and Patient as property in each class and then use `entity.HasOne(x=>x.Patient).WithOne(x=>x.Admission).HasForeignKey("PatientId"); to achieve your requirement.`

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
public class Patient
{
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Nic { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
    public string CurrentState { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public Admission Admission { get; set; }
}
```

Admission:

```
   public class Admission
    {
        public int AdmissionId { get; set; }

         public int PatientId { get; set; }
        public DateTime AdmissionDate { get; set; }
        public string reason { get; set; }

        public Patient Patient{ get; set; }
    }
```

OnModelCreating:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.PatientId);
            entity.Property(e => e.FirstName);
            entity.Property(e => e.LastName);
            entity.Property(e => e.Nic);
            entity.Property(e => e.Age);
            entity.Property(e => e.Address);
            entity.Property(e => e.Email);
            entity.Property(e => e.Mobile);
            entity.Property(e => e.RegisterDate);
            entity.Property(e => e.CurrentState);
            entity.Property(e => e.Password);
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Admission>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.AdmissionId);
            entity.Property(e => e.PatientId);
            entity.Property(e => e.AdmissionDate);
            entity.Property(e => e.reason);
            entity.HasOne(x=>x.Patient).WithOne(x=>x.Admission).HasForeignKey("PatientId");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> You don't need to create foreign key there, just go to the Model that
> you need to add foreign key on it and make a virtual from from the
> model class that you need:

In your case, you can apply it like this:

```
public class Admission
{
    public int AdmissionId { get; set; }
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]   //Add this to avoid create foreign key when scaffolding
    public virtual Patient Patient {get; set;} //Add this to work as foreign key
    public DateTime AdmissionDate { get; set; }
    public string reason { get; set; }
}
```

After that when you need to read the foreign key, you can read it easily as follow:

```
//.Include used to read the foreign key    
var _admission = await db.admission.Include(a => a.Patient).OrderBy(x => x.AdmissionDate);
```

And you can read more about foreign key and relationships from this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key